# HTML Script tag pointing to external source not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm learning node js , so i decided to create a game and was setting up my project but ran into this issue.

My Script tag pointing to external source is not working, But when i copy paste the same javascript code into the html script tag it is working, Here are My code

index.html

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sanke Game</title>
  </head>
  <body>




  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="client.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

client.js

```
const sockt = io("http://localhost:3000/");

sockt.on("serverToClient", function(event){
  alert(event);
})
```

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");


const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
})

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("User is connected");
  socket.on("disconnect", function(){
    console.log("User Disconnected");
  })
  socket.emit("serverToClient", "Hello World");
})


server.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Listening to port 3000");
})
```

All files are in same level.

Comment: @johnSmith that looks like a host relative path to me!

Comment: Check the console for errors and debug from there

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i tried , it just says 404 not found , but the client.js file is available

Comment: Are you sure it's in the same folder as your HTML page?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah its in the same folder

Comment: Your HTTP server has a route for `/` and socket.io provides a route for `/socket.io/socket.io.js`, but you haven't written any code that would serve up `/client.js`

Comment: @johnSmith — phyzi is right, that's a local path, not a hostname. It's set up by `const io = new Server(server);`

Comment: Thank you all for clearing my doubts :)

Comment: i just said that because the title is stating `external resource`

Comment: @johnSmith — It means "external" as in "uses a `src` attribute, not a text node"